# Dynamic HTML Table in PHP Mail

Tags: php, html, mysql, email

I Just wanted to know can we can we include a user defined function in the PHP Mail

```
$to = "example@example.com";
$message = '<html>';
$message .='</html>';
$from = "webmaster@example.com";
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From:" . $from;
```

I tried the above code and i just get the message '< /html>'(without quotes) in my mail. And the function gets printed on the screen. I dont want the function to be printed on the screen i want the function to be run and the contents to be mailed to the user. BTW the function is dynamically generated HTML Table from a MYSQL Database. I've searched on the internet but couldn't find any specific answer.

Comment: The +code itself+ is printed on your screen? Is PHP installed?

Comment: Yes, PHP is installed. The code is just a part of my PHP mail. I just trimmed it out as i have problem in this specific part of the code.

Comment: So, show us what the `displayWinesList()` function does. My guess is that you want to use [`ob_start()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) to capture what's in between your tags.

Comment: Are you putting your PHP code within the PHP tags? `<?php  /* code here */ ?>`

Comment: Yes i've put my code in the PHP Tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are your `displayWinesList()` function echo's its data instead of returning it.

You can either mod your function to return the data or leave it as-is and use output buffering to capture the data:

```
$to = "example@example.com";
$subject = "WineStore Query";
ob_start();
displayWinesList($connection, $query,$region_name, $wine_type, $price);
$message = ob_get_clean();
$message = '<html>'.$message.'</html>';
$from = "webmaster@example.com";
…
```

To know for certain however please post your `displayWinesList()` function.

Comment: I'm not able to add my function implementation here it says the message is too long.

Comment: Post it to pastebin.com then and post the link here.

Comment: Yeah in that function you are `print`'ing the data directly. My answer should work for you.

Comment: I'm printing the function on the page before the $to. So does your answer print out my function again on the screen.

Comment: No it captures the print'ed data to a buffer. It's a 3 line change, just give it a try.

Comment: I've just tried your code... Waiting for the mail...I'll just get back to you with the result... And it didn't print out the function again...Thanks...